# Need to group Time Slots in Excel

Tags: excel

I am working on logistics data. I have booking being made throughout the day at regular intervals from start to the end of the day.
Now these booking are consistent and I have time from like

```
04:45
21:10
21:10
06:07
05:44
05:45
05:45
05:45
etc.
```

Now as there are multiple bookings I need to group them such as 
04:00- 05:00 (1 hours)- this should capture all booking made during this period.
Similar for other hours during the day.
By doing this I will be able to group individual values into specific group. Can you please advice how to achieve the same in excel.

Comment: Please provide more example data and the expected result. It is not really clear from your question what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi I have a requirement from goods are shipped from one location to another at different intervals in a day. This is happening throughout the day. Now there are almost 200 different time slots. In order to summarize the data I need to group these time variables in group. So for all the booking made during interval 3:01am to 3:59 am there are multiple time slots whereas now I want to merge and show all these different bookings into one group namely 3:01 to 3:59 am. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If the values are stored as dates in Excel, the Pivot Table has this functionality built in already with the "Group Field" option.  You can group by Hours which is probably what you want.  Note that you can select multiple items to get a hierarchy of groups as shown below.  This will break if the underlying data is not formatted as a Date so watch out for that.

If you do not have true dates and just have times, you can format as a Time in Excel and it will work.  Just don't show the days/date because it will be gibberish.

[image: image of pivot options]

Comment: Hi Byron this seems to be really helpful and to the point of what I require. HOwever when I tried Grouping, the group field option was not enabled in my pivot table options. What could be the reason? Thanks.

Comment: @Shivi, This usually happens if all of the data is not properly formatted as a date (even a single stray blank cell at the end can cause it).  You can ensure this by selecting the entire column of data (not Pivot) and clearing the formatting and then applying a date or time format.

Answer (score 0):

add a column truncating the time to hours
along the lines of =time(hour(z),0,0)
then create a pivot table using the hour column