# Convert date in Excel to its respective week of the month

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vlookup

Hopeful you can help me out.

I have an Excel spreadsheet open. The spreadsheet has two columns that I need assistance with.

The first column are dates and times that reflect a ticket that opened. The second column reflects dates and times that a ticket closed.

I am needing to correlate all the dates of which every ticket opened and closed to its respective week of the month. So if I have 20 tickets that opened up between the days of 2/22/15 - 2/28/15(all these dates are in the same column fyi...), then I will be needing to somehow correlate these tickets in my spreadsheet to some form of data to be used in a line stack chart.

An exec has laid this on my lap. I don't look useless and I would like a little assistance as to how to perform such a task. Formulas in Excel...Vlookup....or using Pivot Tables....please assist!

Comment: PivotTable with grouping probably gets you close.  You can combine tickets by date and count.  If you have other data, you can aggregate based on that also grouped by date.  Check out this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509320/need-to-group-time-slots-in-excel/29518327#29518327

Answer (score 0):

> convert date in excel to its respective week of the month

in conjunction with the date range example:

```
=INT((DAY(A1)-1)/7)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

In column 3 use the =Weeknum(A1, 1) formula to get the week number of the date in column a. The second argument lets you determine what you want for the beginning of the week to be.
In column 4 do the same for column b. This will give you the week ticket opened/closed respectively. Add column 5 to be the difference in weeks which can be used in a pivot table to show the distribution of tickets and weeks to resolve, etc.

Reply back if you have further needs.

Comment: To get the week of the month you would need to know the week number of the first day of the given month and minus 1 from it. Then take the week number from the open/closed date and minus the above from the open/close week to get the week number of the month. This does mean it won't be full weeks though

Answer (score 0):

Firstly get the week num of the first day of the month -1

```
A1 = 01/02/2018
B1 = =WEEKNUM(A1)-1
```

Then calculate the individiual ticket week numbers and take the week number before the first week of the month away from the returned value. You may need to format the cells as numbers as some reason Excel thinks its a date

```
Open Week = =WEEKNUM(OpenDateCell)-$B$1
Close Week = =WEEKNUM(CloseDateCell)-$B$1
```

Representative Image: [image]